# The turtlebot does not stop when i use the rqt_reconfigure tool

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**The turtlebot does not stop when i use the rqt_reconfigure tool.**

I refered the **ROS by Example _ Hydro - Vol1** book.

I'm trying to calibrate my TurtleBot which is based on iRobot Create 2. But The turtlebot does not stop when i use the rqt_reconfigure tool.

See the procedures i did in this picture :

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220744/the-turtlebot-does-not-stop-when-i-use-the-rqt_reconfigure-tool/) by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2015-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using iRobot Create 2/5xx/6xx  as the driving base. So I need to Configure the launch file and the xml file. Set the robot_type parameter as "ROOMBA" so I can fix this.

---

Originally posted by [sonictl](https://answers.ros.org/users/23111/sonictl/) with karma: 287 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0